# Add Customer Group attribute to Sales Order

Tags: attributes, magento-1, sales-order, ce-1.7.0.2

I have created a new attribute for Customer Groups called `course_id` but I need to get the value of this attribute to then become the value for a new attribute for a Sales Order.

Any ideas how I could do this?

I would assume:

1. Create new Sales Order attribute for Course ID
2. Get value of Customer Group Course ID to set the value for all new Sales Orders attribute for Course ID

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This is my current observer, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. I have added the new new columns in the database (customer group is `course_id` and sales order is `salescourse_id`):

```
<?php 
class MyCompany_CustomerGroupCourseID_Model_Observer 
{
    /**
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return object
     */
    public function setCourseID(Varien_Event_Observer  $observer)
    {
                //get event data
        $event = $observer->getEvent();

                //get order
        $order = $event->getOrder();

        //get current customer group and set course id

         $customerid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        $courseId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($customerid)->getData('course_id');

        if (isset($courseId)){

        $order->setSalescourseId($courseId)

        return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an extra field "course_id" to the `sales_flat_order` table. And you just add an observer on `sales_order_place_before`, to catch the current customer group, and assign it to the current order (you don't even have to save the model, just `$order->setCourseId($courseId)` is sufficient).

Also note that if you want to display this data on the sales order grid, you will have to also add the "course_id" field to the `sales_flat_order_grid` table. (it will be populated automatically when the order model is saved)

Comment: This is my observer, but it doesn't appear to work correctly. See my edit. Thanks for your help.